# Does the FAA provide a CFI knowledge test guide?

Tags: cfi, faa-knowledge-test

The FAA provides the Airman Certification Standards (ACS) for commercial pilots. It discusses the topics asked on the knowledge test. I have only been able to find the Practical Test Standards (PTS) for the Certified Flight Instructor (CFI) practical test. Does the FAA publish a similar document discussing what topics are covered on the *knowledge test*?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/training_testing/testing/test_questions/fia_questions.pdf) to an FAA published document for the "Flight Instructor Airplane" sample knowledge test questions (100 questions). It's current as of August 2021.

Below is an example of the first question from the CFI-Airplane sample knowledge test with the associated "Learning Statement Code" (LSCCode: PLT195).

[image]

From the: [Learning Statement Reference Guide for Airman Knowledge Testing:](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/media/learningstatementreferenceguide.pdf) Clicking on this link will take you to a list of all Learning Statements and their associated area of necessary knowledge.

> General: The expression ‘learning statement,’ as used in airman testing, refers to measurable
> statements of knowledge that a student should be able to demonstrate following a defined
> element of training. In order that the individual learning statements may be read as complete
> sentences, they should be assumed to be preceded by the words: “Upon the successful
> completion of training the student should be able to . . . . "

> The LSCCode PLT195 refers to: "PLT195 Recall collision avoidance - TCAS"

---

---

---

[Here is a link](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_questions) to other FAA published sample knowledge test questions for various airman certificates/ratings.

As of now, this is no ACS for the Flight Instructor practical test.